# Background color in my div is not showing up

Tags: css, html, colors

I have searched on the web for an answer to my problem. Of course it led me to a few topics here on stackoverflow. I tried the solutions that where offered, but I had no succes so far! Would someone please be so kind to take a quick look at my html & css? It's about the sidebar id. I have defined the background color to red so you should not be able to miss it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Eenmaal Andermaal</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            table { 
                border-spacing:10px;
            }

            <!---Veiling foto's--->
            .imgBig {
                width: 252px;
                height: 252px;
            }

            .imgSmall {
                width: 80px;
                height: 80px;
            }

            #enlarged {
                float:left;
            }

            #thumbnails {
                float:left;
            }

            <!---Bod bar--->
            #sidebar {
                float:left;
                width:272px;
                height:739px;
                background-color:red;
            }

            <!---Links--->
            a {
                text-decoration:none;
                color:#535f79;
            }

            a:hover {
                text-decoration:underline;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>Titel van deze veiling</h2>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Voorwerpnummer:</td><td>7324474820</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <!--Foto's-->

        <div id="enlarged">
            <img class = "imgBig" src = "img\versterker.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div id="thumbnails">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="img\versterker.jpg"><img class = "imgSmall" src = "img\versterker.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="img\versterker.jpg"><img class = "imgSmall" src = "img\versterker.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="img\versterker.jpg"><img class = "imgSmall" src = "img\versterker.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="img\versterker.jpg"><img class = "imgSmall" src = "img\versterker.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <!--Biedingen-->
        <div id="sidebar">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Verkoper:</td><td>Gebruiker793</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Locatie:</td><td>Arnhem</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Beoordeling:</td><td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                     <td><a href>Neem contact op met verkoper</a></td><td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Geplaatst:</td><td>22-11-2013 11:00</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Looptijd:</td><td>7 dagen</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The CSS isn't valid because of the comments: `<!---Veiling foto's--->` This is an HTML comment.

> [**CSS Syntax - 4.1.9 Comments**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#comments)
>
> [In CSS] comments begin with the characters "/*" and end with the characters "*/". They may occur anywhere outside other tokens, and their contents have no influence on the rendering. Comments may not be nested.

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/WHqN7/1/)

Updated CSS

```
table {
    border-spacing:10px;
}
/* Veiling foto's */
 .imgBig {
    width: 252px;
    height: 252px;
}
.imgSmall {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
#enlarged {
    float:left;
}
#thumbnails {
    float:left;
}
/* bod bar */
 #sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:272px;
    height:739px;
    background-color:red;
}
/* Links */
 a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#535f79;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Format of comment should be /* comment */

Write:

```
table {
    border-spacing:10px;
}
/*Veiling foto's*/
 .imgBig {
    width: 252px;
    height: 252px;
}
.imgSmall {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
#enlarged {
    float:left;
}
#thumbnails {
    float:left;
}
/*Bod bar*/
 #sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:272px;
    height:739px;
    background-color:red;
}
/*Links*/
 a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#535f79;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/28ba6/1)

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong comments `<!---Bod bar--->` its for html . For css you need `/* Comment goes here*/`.

Your markup is also invalid . I think your image source should be `img/versterker.jpg` instead of `img\versterker.jpg`

Comment: Quite a few stupid mistakes I made. Thanks a lot all for the quick solutions!